# Deleting previous results from Data Collection Results tab

Tags: ptv-vissim

I ran my PTV Vissim simulation a few times to see if it works. I noticed that the Data Collection Results tab collected all the data from these runs. How can I delete these previous data?

Edit:
I think I was able to figure it out: 1) you have to delete/move the files from the "results" folder in the same directory, 2) close out the simulation, 3) then open the simulation again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one way is to simply delete the `results` folder and re-open the network.

However, from within Vissim you can go to the menu <kbd>Evaluation</kbd> → <kbd>Result lists</kbd> → <kbd>Simulation runs</kbd> and in the opening list delete the obsolete (or all) simulation runs (this will also remove the corresponding evaluation results).

There is also the option in <kbd>Evaluation</kbd> → <kbd>Configuration</kbd>, Tab <kbd>Result management</kbd>, to keep the result of the "current (multi-)run only". Selecting this will automatically throw away existing results every time you start a new simulation.